# Removing columns from a Matrix MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ; 
 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ; 
 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ]
```

The last row has five columns with zeros. I would like to keep only one column per zero crossing.

like this

```
[1 2 3 5 8 9 ; 
 9 8 7 5 2 1 ; 
 1 2 0 1 0 1 ]
```

Is this possible with fast Matlab functions or do I have to write some slow complicated for loop ?

Comment: I believe you can do something similar to what I explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758319/matrix-as-input-and-output-of-matlab-function. Could please clarify what is your criteria for selecting which column you want to keep? I am asking because it seems you kept the first column in the first part of your example and the last one in the latter.

Comment: You can use answers to the "find zero crossings" questions, construct a 1d logical index vector `ind`, and then `mat(:,ind)=[]` to delete those columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a logical array many different ways to find the columns to remove. Something like this would work

```
% Find the zeros that are not the first zero
cols_to_remove = data(end,:) == 0 & ~diff([false, data(end,:) == 0]) == 1;

% Now remove them
data(:, cols_to_remove) = [];
```

Comment: @AndrasDeak Doh. yes

Comment: Thanks mate, easily the smartest thing i've seen the last ten days.